# How would I pass parameter inside comment section in SQL mapper xml

Tags: mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

I have this requirement like setting a dynamic unique id inside the comment section of sql mapper so that it will be printed in log for future reference.i got the unique id generated and set it into the query parameter map using interceptor.This unique id param is used inside comment section as below

```
<select id=" getContacts" parameterType="map" resultMap="Contact">
**<!-- some log information with unique id #{uid}-->**
  SELECT * FROM CONTACT 
  WHERE CONTACT_NAME = #{name}
  AND CONTACT_PHONE = #{phone}
  AND CONTACT_MAIl = #{email}
</select>
```

#{uid} is the param which i set inside the comment section.
It seems not working as expected.
What is the best way to achieve this.Any suggestion?

Comment: Try with ${uid} and put it as parameter. Take a look the section String subsitution which is inside Parameter section:
http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Parameters